# Mqttjs websocket support

Tags: websocket, mqtt

I'm experimenting with [mqttjs](https://npmjs.org/package/mqttjs) and websockets and I wish to be able to send messages from a webpage using websockets *without* a bridge to an MQTT broker that is run by mqttjs. I can't find any information if this is available or even possible.

I've looked at mosquitto and they have "[experimental](http://test.mosquitto.org/ws.html)" websocket support and I would love to find a Node.JS MQTT broker which could offer the same.

Thus far I got the communication working with pywebsocket and Socket.IO. I would really appreciate pointers in any direction if it is possible to use websockets to mqtt without bridging.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is old question but is good to share my findings.
You can use the mosca broker that is written in node.js and is using mqtt.js
The mosca is supporting classic mqtt connection and mqtt over WS :
[MQTT-over-Websockets](https://github.com/mcollina/mosca/wiki/MQTT-over-Websockets)

Mosca can operate in two modes: Standalone and as a node.js module.

In general mosca can support many types of brokers:
[Mosca-advanced-usage](https://github.com/mcollina/mosca/wiki/Mosca-advanced-usage)

Answer (score 1):

[HiveMQ](http://www.hivemq.com) supports native websockets, which means you can use any Javascript MQTT library (like [Eclipse Paho.js](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/) with websockets. It's perfectly possible to connect some clients vie websockets and other clients via standard TCP connection. The websocket support is stable and used in production.

The only drawback for you could be that HiveMQ is not written in Node.JS.

Disclosure: I am one of the developers of HiveMQ.